# How to pass python function to another function with flag

Tags: python

I have created verbose_on (it shows output if used) and verbose_off fuction. In verbose_on(fn), fn is another function.

helper.py

```
import os
import sys
import io
def verbose_on(fn):
    sys.stdout = io.StringIO()
    fn()
    output = sys.stdout.getvalue()
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    print(output)


def verbose_off(fn):
    sys.stdout = io.StringIO()
    fn()
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    print('Task Completed.')
```

/dev.py

In sample function there are some commands, whose output need to be showed in test function if verbose is on.

```
def sample(flag2):
    print('tests are running')
    # another commands running
```

/main.py

It has test function which has two flags, one to activate verbose and another flag which is needed to pass with sample.
Check helper.verbose_off(sample) in test function, it is passing sample which will be converted to function in verbose_on method(fn(), i.e. sample())

```
from dev import sample
from helper import verbose_on, verbose_off
def test(verbose, flag2):
    if verbose:
        print('Verbose mode = On.')
        helper.verbose_on(sample)
    else:
        print('Verbose mode = Off')
        helper.verbose_off(sample)
```

But it is needed that flag2 shoud be pass with sample inside test function, something  like this : **helper.verbose_on(sample(flag2))**.
Any suggestions  will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you think of a [partial function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)?

Comment: use ```lambda x: sample(flag)```

Comment: @VladimirVilimaitis it is something  similar.

Comment: @Sifat please provide more information,  maybe example  would be  great. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @NIKHILPIMPARE another user already added.

Comment: You could add `*args` and possibly `**kwargs` to `verbose_on` and pass those on to `fn`, then call as `verbose_on(sample, flag2)`

Comment: @tobias_k def verbose_on(*args, *kwargs) something  like this?

Comment: Don't forget the function itself, i.e. `def verbose_on(fn, *args, **kwargs)`, that calls `fn(*args, **kwargs)`, and you call `verbose_on(sample, flag2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lambda functions:

```
def test(verbose, flag2):
    if verbose:
        print('Verbose mode = On.')
        helper.verbose_on(lambda: sample(flag2))
```

or [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
def test(verbose, flag2):
    if verbose:
        print('Verbose mode = On.')
        helper.verbose_on(functools.partial(sample, flag2))
```

Comment: if we use functools.partial then do we need to do changes in verbose_on method?

Comment: No, `functools.partial` will return a callable object, which will be called by the `fn()` statement in `verbose_on/off`. Even after the change, only one argument is passed to verbose_on/off.